TKintermapview image size adjustment
I'm working on a Python code that displays the position of a train on a map in real time.
In order to do so I use tkinter and tkintermapview, I can display the map, the icon, different overlay no problem.
The issue is that I can't figure out how to adjust the size of the images and overlay to the zoom
I searched for how to get the zoom value in order to link it to the image size, so I tried to read some documentation, asked chatGPT and it keep giving me false info like use map_widget.get_zoom() which is not a thing:

"AttributeError: 'TkinterMapView' object has no attribute 'get_zoom'"


you can use print( dir(map_widget) ) to see what functions has this object.

I never hear about tkintermapview. In question (not in comments) you could add link to home page and documentation.

source code shows that it has self.zoom - so maybe try to use print( map_widget.zoom )

source code shows that TkinterMapView has self.zoom so use map_widget.zoom
print( map_widget.zoom )

